# How to set default screen brightness on power profile in 22.04?

Tags: power-management, 22.04, brightness

Is there a way for me to set the different power profiles on 22.04 to change the screen brightness when I pick them?  Right now the screen stays the same brightness across the different power profiles, so when I have swap profiles I have to manually change the screen brightness.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't currently. That could be by design. The power profiles set parameters related to how the processor runs. Changing screen brightness to save power is another, independent way to save power. Not all users would be happy with an automatic change in brightness when manually changing the power profile.